# Int array to prime to boolean array

Tags: java, boolean

I am supposed to evaluate an array of integers and determine whether they are prime. Once I do that, I have to return (to main) an array of booleans.

```
public static boolean [] Advanced_7(int Array []){

    boolean [] verdict = new boolean [Array.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++)
    {
        verdict[i] = true; 

        for(int j = 2; j <= Array[i]; j++)
        {
             if (Array[i] % j == 0) 
             {
                 verdict[i] = false;  
             }
         }
    }

    return verdict;
}
```

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to explain **HOW** this code isn't working, we can't be bothered to try and GUESS what the problem might be.

Comment: run step by step for a small set of small numbers and you'll see.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier could be java, too.

Comment: Sorry. This is in java.

Comment: This is how I called it from the main.
int dj [] = {1,2,3,4};
boolean [] ah = Advanced_7(dj);
System.out.println(ah);

Comment: This is what it returns:
[Z@35afe17b

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: I need to be able to get the following while entering the following:
input: 1,2,3,4
output; true, true, true, false

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question, rather than posting miscellaneous snippets in comments.  And remember it's your instructor's job to help you understand these concepts; try asking them directly.

Comment: your function does not look so bad, although there are a few things that could be made better. The problem actually is in the way you output the result. And btw. 1 is not a prime.

Comment: An array is an object, so you can't print it directly. Once you execute your function, you need to traverse the array(s) and print each element.

Comment: Where are you printing the result of `Advanced_7()` method? How are you printing it? Please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.` For better help sooner please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **Hint:** To print the array value print *each* element **not** the array as one (i.e. `System.out.println(array)` instead loop through it

Answer (score 1):

Just some general hints:

First:  the way you're checking wether a number is prime or not can be simplified; you only need to check the elements up to *half* the integer you're checking.

Second: once you know the number is non-prime, why do you keep checking? Break the `for` loop once you know the number is non-prime.

Third: To output your results to the console, you can't simply print the object (an array is an object, so whatever get's printed can look quite wierd). In your `main` procedure, store the result in a variable, and print each entry with a `for` loop.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you should use Java naming conventions. The code below is a rewrite of your original code, using those conventions and applying the suggestions I gave you above.

```
public static boolean[] checkForPrimes(int[] numbers) {
/*
    The name for the function should be a verbe, and start 
    with a lower case letter.
    The input parameter for the function is an object, and 
    must also start with a lower case letter.
 */
    boolean[] veredict = new boolean[numbers.length];
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        veredict[i] = true;
        // You only need to check up to half each number
        for(j = 2; j <= numbers[i] / 2; j++) {
            if(numbers[i] % j == 0) {
                veredict[i] = false;
                break; // once you know the number is non-prime
                       // exit the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return veredict;
}
public static void printResult(int[] numbers) {
    boolean[] veredict = checkForPrimes(numbers);
    // You must traverse the arrays to print them out:
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i] + " " + veredict[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: for the first point: actually checking up to the square root is enough

Comment: @Henry Indeed... but let's keep it simple using only elementary operations ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following contains a couple of unexplained changes.
If you can explain them, use them.

```
int element = Array[i];
verdict[i] = element % 2 == 0;
if (verdict[i])
{
    for (int j = 3; j <= element / 2; j += 2)
    {
         if (element % j == 0) 
         {
             verdict[i] = false;
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

For fast printing you might use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(verdict));
```

Comment: `for (int j = 3; j * j <= element; j += 2)` is even faster.

Comment: @Henry indeed much better, best `j <= square root of element` unfortunately not as primitive available. For those that want to experiment: `for (int j = 3, qj = 9; qj <= element; j += 2, qj += (j - 1) << 2)`. _Cryptoprogramming not gaining an school points!_